# No puedo conectar mi contact form con mi correo

Tags: html5, phpmailer, contact-form-7

Tengo mi código HTML5 CSS Y PHP, al momento de hacer prueba de envió en mi Contact Form, no me conecta con mi correo. He intentado ya varias formas, pero ninguna lo conecta, y no me llega nada. Que puedo hacer para lograr conectar.[Aquíles dejo el enlace de la web que he creado](http://photographyytravels.rf.gd/)
[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]]

Comment: Intenta con $_POST y no `$_post`, además puedes que los emails estén llegando a la carpeta de spam

Comment: Lo intentaré, gracias.   No, a la carpeta de Spam no llega nada tampoco

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar debes hacer uso de la función `PHP Mail()` (que por cierto no veo que la uses en ningún lado), esta es la que te permite enviar correos desde una pagina web o servidor.

La función tiene los siguientes parámetros `mail(to, subject, message, headers, parameters);`.

Los únicos importantes y que se requieren son los tres primeros, los demás son opcionales, te dejo un ejemplo a continuación:

```
$to = "destinatario@email.com";
$subject = "Asunto del email";
$message = "Este es mi primer envío de email con PHP";
 
mail($to, $subject, $message);
```

Comment: Iré a corregir esa parte, gracias.     Por favor me indicas dónde debo poner el PHP Mail( )